# How many digits are there in $99^{99}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mental-arithmetic

> Question: How many digits are there in $99^{99}$?

My attempt:

Observe that 
$$99^{99} = (100\times 0.99)^{99} = 100^{99}\times 0.99^{99}.$$
Note that $100^{99} = 10^{198}$ has $199$ digits and 
$$0.99^{99} = \left(1-\frac{1}{100}\right)^{99} \approx e^{-1} \approx 0.37.$$
Therefore, there are $198$ digits in $99^{99}.$

Is my reasoning above correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. An even simpler argument is that since $\left(1-\frac1x\right)^x$ is increasing, $0.99^{99}>0.25$.

Comment: should probably note $0.99^{99}<1$

Comment: $99^{99} = 369729637649726772657187905628805440595668764281741102430259972423552570455277523421410650010128232727940978889548326540119429996769494359451621570193644014418071060667659301384999779999159200499899$

Answer (score 2):

Number of digits in $99^{99}$ are $1+[99\log_{10} 99]= [198.568]=198$
Here [.] denotes integer-part. So 198 digits is the correct answer.